# Get formatted output for integer variable in cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to output some data in many files with names file01.txt, file02.txt, ... , file10.txt, file11.txt. I have following script:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a cnt = 0
for /f %%f in ('dir /b "../in/"') do (
    set /a cnt += 1
    get_data > ../out/file!cnt!.txt
)
```

But I get files file1.txt, file2.txt. How can I format it and add needed zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```dos
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a cnt = 100
for /f %%f in ('dir /b "..\in\"') do (
    set /a cnt += 1
    get_data > ..\out\file!cnt:~-2!.txt
)
```

Substrings in batch are obtained from `%var:~m,n%` where `,n` is optional; `m` is count-of-chars-from-beginning-of-string, from end if negative. `,n` positive = max length to return; negative = end-position in chars from end; missing=return all after `m`

Answer (score 1):

Workaround:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a cnt=0
for /f %%f in ('dir /b "../in/"') do (
    set /a cnt += 1
    set s="../out/file"
    if !cnt! lss 10 (
        set s="../out/file0"
    )
    get_data  > !s!!cnt!.txt
)
```